# How to hide a folder in NTFS for particular user

Tags: php, svn, filesystems, ntfs

I have a Problem with PHP and SVN. [See here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600997/how-can-i-hide-svn-directories-from-php)
Using [FUSE](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=OperatingSystems) would be one option, but after a first look, it seems very complicated.

Is there any option to prevent an NTFS filesystem, WIN2003Server, to hide directories completely from a useraccount (I can setup apache to run under this account).

It is not as easy as it seems, given the following restrictions:

- It must be a pattern match, I do not know in advance which SVN folders will be created
- I cant deny the access to the whole parent folder, the .SVN and the content lay side by side
- Simply hiding does not work, PHP does not care for hidden flag

Any ideas (or comments)?

Comment: FUSE isn't really an option on Windows.

Comment: Also, to be honest, this is sort of a duplicate. You could have just edited your question to have this information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is no: Permissions in NTSF do not allow hiding of folders.
Here is a list of all permissions you can grant/revoke in NTFS:

- Full Control (includes everything from below)
- Traverse Folder
- List Folder
- Read Attributes
- Read Extended Attributes
- Create Files
- Create Folders
- Write Attributes
- Write Extended Attributes
- Delete
- Read Permissions
- Change Permissions
- Take Ownership

Ignoring single files/directories is what the hidden attribute is for. If the program (typo3, right?) ignores the flag, your best bet is to see if you can *configure* it to 
handle it. (But that would be a new question on SO).